# Angular custom module with a factory function not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to do some additional configuration injection, and found a few good articles to do this, however, I cannot get my example to work.

To start off with, my custom module:

```
@NgModule()
export class AppConfigModule {

  static forRoot(config?: FunkyConfig): ModuleWithProviders {

    return({
      ngModule: AppConfigModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: FUNKY_CONFIG,
          useValue: config
        },
        {
          provide: FunkyConfigClass,
          useFactory: appConfigFactory,
          deps: [FUNKY_CONFIG],
          multi: true
        }
      ]
    });
  }
}
```

The `useFactory` portion of this code just never triggers.

My **app.config** looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from 'app/app.component';
import { LayoutModule } from 'app/layout/layout.module';
import { TestModule } from 'app/main/test/test.module';
import { AppConfigModule } from './app-config.module';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path      : '**',
        redirectTo: 'test'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),

        AppConfigModule.forRoot(),

        // App modules
        LayoutModule,
        TestModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule
{
}
```

Within the factory function, I'm currently just having a debugger; as I want to ensure that this code is hit, yet, nothing.

Am I not understanding how this works?

I do `ng s --watch` so that changes are automatically refreshed.

**Update**

I did not correctly inject this in my service. Thanks everyone.

Comment: methinks the factory function will not be called unless you afterwards try to inject FunkyConfigClass

Comment: the factory will only get called when it gets injected into another service or component

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
@NgModule()
export declare class AppConfigModule {
  static forRoot(config?: FunkyConfig): ModuleWithProviders;
}

export declare class FunkConfig {
   // your config
}
```

Comment: You end up with errors about operations within an ambient context, if you introduce any logic.